# Executing Javascript code after submission of asp.net form

Tags: asp.net

How do I execute Javascript after submission of an ASP.NET form?

For example, if I got a submit button click after submission of page then I want to display a DIV which I have hidden on page.

Comment: Does OnClientClick not do what you need it to do?

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC? Are you submitting the form via Postback or using JavaScript?

Comment: i got submit button with runat="server" option so form is sent to sever side . onclientclick execute before submision .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would only want to convert the hidden div to a visible one then that can be done on the server side. In the aspx, give the div an id and a runat="server". Then in the server side, set its display style attribute to 'block'. For example, say the div is defined as

```
<div id="divTest" runat="server" style="display:none;">
        This is a div test
</div>
```

Then in the post event of the submit button you can set its style as given below:

```
divTest.Style["display"] = "block";
```

If you only want to emit scripts after the post then using the ScriptManager you could use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptRegisterTest", "alert('Testing');", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a full postback, you can easily include the javascript from the code-behind.

Place your JavaScript Code inside a Placeholder

```
<asp:Placeholder ID="javascriptPlaceholder" runat="server" Visible="false">
 <%-- Your Javascript here -->
</asp:Placeholder>
```

I assume in your OnClick handling method, you are getting the value of the form and do something else with it. In this method you could set the Visibile property of the placeholder:

```
this.javascriptPlaceholder.Visible = true;
```

Comment: this is the only answer that addresses the general question asked instead of the specific example case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but if you're going back to the server and doing some processing, why do you need javascript?  Just add a runat="server" to the div in question and make it visible after the processing.

```
<div id="YourDiv" runat="server" Visible="false" >
    ...Whatever is here
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   /* 
    Your Logic Here
   */
   YourDiv.Visible = true;  
}
```